# Lingering Hibernate sessions without transaction in JBoss

Tags: hibernate, spring, jboss

I have encountered a Hibernate issue I just can't find my way around. We're running Hibernate 3.2.6 on JBoss 4.2.0, in a Spring 2.5.4 application behind JBossWS 2.0.1 (just to get all the version on the table).

Normally this works just fine, but sometime the system spontaneously (i.e. for some reason currently not know to us) enters a state where some requests fail on first Hibernate call with "org.hibernate.HibernateException: Current transaction is not in progress". This affects random requests until server restart. I am unable to reproduce this and are currently "reacting" to when it happens (so far only in test environments.

I have managed to trigger the same behaviour when the JBoss transaction timeout hits and the server code proceeds with Hibernate calls, but never without the preceeding Arjuna coordinator logs of aborting the action and never had it reappear on subsequent calls.

Off the top of my head I'm suspecting that a thread "state" is somehow retained from a preceeding call and when that thread is then re-used for another request, it results in no transaction being started. I have working knowledge of Hibernate, not much more, but as transactions and sessions work otherwise that's what I've come up with.

Can you give me any pointers into investigations and/or configurations I should look into?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that there is a bug, I'm assuming that we have some kind of misconfiguration or misuse that causes this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was in fact a Hibernate bug that under certain conditions left sessions behind! Upgrading to Hibernate 3.3 resolved the issue.